# SQL row value ranked as ordinal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
╔═══════════════════════╗
║ id   name       spent ║
╠═══════════════════════╣
║ 1    John       1000  ║
║ 2    Bob        2000  ║
║ 3    Richard    5000  ║
║ 4    Jane       2000  ║
║ 5    Anthony    2500  ║
╚═══════════════════════╝
```

I'd like to retrieve a row and rank the spent column like this

```
SELECT name, 
       spent 
FROM   table 
WHERE  id = 5 ;
```

and the desired result be something like this:

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║   name       spent   ║
╠══════════════════════╣
║ Anthony   2500 (2nd) ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

That is, Anthony is the second who spent most (after Richard's 5000)
and if I wanted to order by who spent less it would be something like this

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║   name       spent   ║
╠══════════════════════╣
║ Anthony   2500 (4th) ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I don't see an attempt...

Comment: If you search for "mysql rank" in SO, I'll bet you'll find lots of answers -- this is a common need.

Comment: I've just found an interesting approach to count how many rows have spent value greater or less than the current rows value like `select count(1) from users 
where spent > (select spent from users where id = 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**Order by who spent less**

```
SELECT id, name, group_concat(spent,' (', rank,')') as t from (
  SELECT id, name, spent, FIND_IN_SET( spent, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( spent 
                        ORDER BY spent) 
FROM t1 )
) AS rank
FROM t1) as y 
where id = 5
group by id, name 
order by spent;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3acaf/41/0)

**Order By who spent more**

```
SELECT id, name, group_concat(spent,' (', rank,')') as t from (
  SELECT id, name, spent, FIND_IN_SET( spent, (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( spent 
                        ORDER BY spent DESC) 
FROM t1 )
) AS rank
FROM t1) as y 
where id = 5
group by id, name 
order by spent;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3acaf/42/0)